# Get certain information from JSON_DECODE

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to explain this as best as I can, please ask i'm im unclear about something.
I'm using a API where i get a bunch of information about a sensor.

This is a method in a class

```
public function getSensors()
 {
     $params = array();
     return json_decode($this->consumer->sendRequest(constant('REQUEST_URI').'/sensors/list', $params, 'GET')->getBody());
```

And in my **index.php**

```
$params = array('id'=> XXXXXX); 
$response = $consumer->sendRequest(constant('REQUEST_URI').'/sensor/info', $params,'GET');

echo json_decode($response->getBody());
```

This gives me a chunk of information like this:

```
{"id":"xxxxx","client":"xxxx","name":"xxxxx","lastUpdated": xxxx}
```

I only want to use **some** of this information.

This is the getBody() method-

```
public function getBody() {
    if (self::METHOD_POST == $this->method && (!empty($this->postParams) || !empty($this->uploads))) {

        if (0 === strpos($this->headers['content-type'], 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')) {

            $body = http_build_query($this->postParams, '', '&');

            if (!$this->getConfig('use_brackets')) {

                $body = preg_replace('/%5B\d+%5D=/', '=', $body);

            }

            // support RFC 3986 by not encoding '~' symbol (request #15368)

            return str_replace('%7E', '~', $body);



        } elseif (0 === strpos($this->headers['content-type'], 'multipart/form-data')) {

            require_once 'HTTP/Request2/MultipartBody.php';

            return new HTTP_Request2_MultipartBody(

                $this->postParams, $this->uploads, $this->getConfig('use_brackets')

            );

        }

    }

    return $this->body;

}
```

Comment: `so i can modify it with CSS` what do you mean by that

Comment: echo json_decode() shouldn't be able to work if the body of the response is a correct JSON object as you would be trying to echo a PHP object. JSON_Decode decodes a JSON string and returns a PHP object which you can then manipulate to output selectively or ouput as HTML.

Comment: Alexander - Thanks for the response. I'm not sure I follow. Is the last part a PHP object? And if so, how can i manipulate it? Thanks.

Comment: JSON itself is a string with a specific format that can be universally decoded. At what point in your code is it in string form? Once it has been decoded then it should give you an array or object. Try using this while debugging echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode($json_string), true).'</pre>';

Comment: MonkeyZeus - I actually don't think it ever is in String form. It's an array I believe. I didn't get print_r to work but i used var_dump and it looks like an array. { ["id"]=> string(6) "XXXXXX" ["clientName"]=> string(12) "

Comment: So i'll guess I wonder how i can take e.g the clientName from that and use it as normal text in HTML.

Comment: Search google for json tutorials

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an API you can't control what information you get unless the API defines a method to do so. If you're reading sensors then it's unlikely that will be an option.

Nevertheless, you can just ignore what you don't need.

For example:

```
$myArray = json_decode('{"id":"xxxxx","client":"xxxx","name":"xxxxx","lastUpdated": xxxx}');
$mySubset = array($myArray['id'], $myArray['lastUpdated']);
```

I just use `json_decode` to illustrate the point. From your comments it looks like `getBody()` is returning an array, but the error message you report points to an object.

For an array you can use

```
$myResp = $response->getBody();
$myId = $myResp['id'];
```

For an object you can use

```
$myResp = $response->getBody();
$myId = $myResp->id;
```

Apologies if I don't quite hit the mark - I'm firing a little blind here!

Comment: Mike W - Thanks! I think thats a step in the right directions, however getBody() is a object and I don't really know how to use it. If i go like you said but i put $response->getBody() inside the json_decode i'll get an error saying "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string".

Comment: Mike W - I'd say you're firing completley blind, lol. I'm clueless, so all help is really appreciated. If i use the one for array, it says its "Illegal string offset", if I use the method for a object, it says i'm trying to get property of a non-object.

Comment: Then I really can't help any more - I really need to know what getBody() is returning before I can add anything nore.

Comment: Mike W - I found the getBody() method. I have edited my first post, if you have time to take a look. I really appreciate the help. :))